# RedirectToAction is not sending users to correct page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect

I want to redirect the user if the date is past 5/25/2020
otherwise they get the current view

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime expirationDate = new DateTime(2020, 05, 25);

        if (dt > expirationDate)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home");
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Code from HomeController.cs

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.Name;
        string userIdfromCache = SaveToCache("UserID", userId);
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Authentication");
    }

    public IActionResult ThankYou()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The IActionResult ThankYou() is not redirecting the user. It should display a static HTML file

Comment: Do you have any kind of authorization? Maybe you forgot to change the authorization in the HomeController, which leads to redirecting to the login page if you're not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only return in the ActionResult is the View(). Replace  `RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home");` with  `return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home");` and it should work

Comment: I did that too but it somehow gets into a ReDirect loop and then my app crashes

Comment: This is probably caused by the code in the Home/ThankYou. I recreated this in an empty project and adding the "return" fixed it for me. Could you edit your question and add the code in Home/ThankYou?

Comment: when the redirect happens, it just refreshes the current page as if nothing happens then it enters a loop. It never touches the controller on the redirected page (i set up breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is somewhere else, I tried your code it works just fine!